# How to write a SQL query to find the range from column values?

Tags: mysql

I have some fields in my database which contain values like 2483-5802 and 1245-3325.

Now I have a user input and I have to find it from this column.
Example if I have to search 2000 which will come in range 1245-3325.

So how I can write a query to find that 2000 belongs to 1245-3325 this range?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: thats mysql database.

Comment: How come the value 2000 belongs to the 2483-5802 range? Shouldn't it belong in the 1245-3325 range?

Comment: that was just an example. but thanks ill update my question :)

Comment: The start and end of the range should be stored in 2 separate integer columns. Not in one varchar column.

Answer (score 0):

As follows (replace `yourtable` and each of the two instances of `rangefield`):

```
SELECT *
FROM `yourtable`
WHERE ? BETWEEN CAST(`rangefield` AS int) AND CAST(MID(`rangefield`, LOCATE('-', `rangefield`)+1) AS int);
```